# Neural Network loss function and weight matrix doesn't match

Tags: python, matrix, neural-network

I'm attempting to learn about neural networks using matrices and in doing so I decided to set myself a challenge, train a simple neural network to output 0.5*sigma(x).

My guess is this would be sufficient as W needs to be 0.5.

[image]

But I've run into a problem regarding the loss function and the weights.

```
import sys
import math
import numpy as np
import random

@np.vectorize
def dlossbydw(X,W,Y):
    t = np.dot(X,W)
    Yhat = sig(t)
    n = Y-Yhat
    l = 2*n * -1 * sig(t)*(1-sig(t))*X
    return l

@np.vectorize
def sig(Z):
    return (1.0/ (1.0 + math.exp(-Z)))

@np.vectorize
def toMatch(Z):
    return 0.5*sig(Z)

def main(args):
    #This is the matrix that should be output
    Y = np.array([[toMatch(x)] for x in range(-5,5)])

    #This is the input matix
    X = np.array([[x] for x in range(-5,5)])

    random.seed(5)
    r = random.random()

    #And this is the weight matrix
    W = np.array([r])

    rate = 1e-1
    for i in range(1000):
        print("dlossbydw: " + str(dlossbydw(X,W,Y)))
        #???

    print("expected out:" + str(Y))
    print("post training:" + str(sig(np.dot(X,W))))

if(__name__=="__main__"):
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

The dimensions of the weight matrix W is 1x1, (there is only one weight connecting the input neuron and the output) however when I do the math to calculate the loss with respect to w, it gives me a 10x1 matrix, my guess is it gives me the loss for each X inputted for the input matrix, but what do I do with this? Each value in the loss is different from the last, which is strange considering they all require the same shift in W. (towards 0.5)

[image]

I must be misunderstanding something, or confusing myself over a simple mistake.

Can someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong here?

What should I be doing at the place marked?

Is this correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a NN with one weight, one input, no bias and a sigmoid activation function the output is calculated like this:

```
y = sig(w*x)
```

If you're trying to match `0.5*sig(x)` the weight `w` is not necessarily 0.5.

I played a little around with your code:

Make sure that your weights have the right shape. It currently has `(1,)`. I fixed that like:

```
random.seed(5)
W = np.array([random.random()])
W.shape=(1,1)
```

Your math is otherwise correct. The problem is, that you have to distinguish between component-wise multiplication and the dot product using `numpy` like this:

```
 l = np.dot(X.T, 2*n * -1 * sig(t)*(1-sig(t)))
```

And get rid of `np.vectorize` for `dlossbydw` because it shouldn't be applied to individual elements of the vector since you need the dot product in the end to get one scalar value.

`l` is now a 1x1 matrix, which gives you the gradient for your weight to adapt.

```
for i in range(1000):
    l = dlossbydw(X,W,Y)
    print("dlossbydw: " + str(l))
    W = W-l
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, I was just coming here to comment that I figured out the answer to the problem (that no matter the value of W when input is 0 the output can't be warped to 0.25, I need a weight after the neuron for that), but you fixed some big issues I didn't notice.

Comment: No worries, you're welcome. I just added some more information.